# A question about Galois extension and splitting field of an irreducible polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, galois-extensions

Let $E$ be the splitting field of an irreducible $f(x)\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$, $Gal(E/\mathbb{Q})$ is abelian. Prove that $E = \mathbb{Q}(a)$, where $a$ is one of the roots of $f(x)$.

My attempt:

Let $K$ be any intermediate field between $E$ and $\mathbb{Q}$, then

1) is it true that $K/\mathbb{Q}$ is a Galois extension $\iff$ $Gal(E/K)$ is a normal subgroup of $Gal(E/\mathbb{Q})$?

Because if it is, then $\mathbb{Q}(a)$ being an intermediate field between $E$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ would lead lead to $\mathbb{Q}(a)/\mathbb{Q}$ being a Galois extension (because every subgroup of an Abelian group $Gal(E/\mathbb{Q})$ is normal and thus $Gal(E/\mathbb{Q}(a))$ is a normal subgroup of $Gal(E/\mathbb{Q})$). This means all roots of $f(x)$ are in $\mathbb{Q}(a)\implies E\subset \mathbb{Q}(a)$ and clearly $Q(a)\subset E$. $\therefore E = \mathbb{Q}(a)$.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. $K/\mathbb{Q}$ is obviously separable because it is an algebraic extension of a field of characteristic $0$. And according to the fundamental theorem of Galois theory it is normal if and only if $Gal(E/K)\trianglelefteq Gal(E/\mathbb{Q})$.

Comment: You may use the fixed fields : $E/K/Q$ and $E/Q$ is Galois means $Q = E^G$ for some finite subgroup $G \le Aut(E)$, let $H = Aut(E/K)$ then $K = E^H$ (because $K(a)/K$ is separable and its monomorphisms can be extended to $E$) and for any $g \in G, g|_K\in G/H$ sends $K=E^H$ to $E^{g H g^{-1}}$, if also $G$ is abelian then $E^{g H g^{-1}}=K$ so $G/H$ is a finite subgroup of $Aut(K)$ and $K^{G/H} = (E^H)^{G/H} = E^G = Q$ and $K/Q$ is Galois abelian.